# Deleting files: NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android, delete-file, java-io

I am using this logic to delete files in sdcard. It is deleting all the files, but I am getting NullPointer exceptions in Logs during the file delete operation.  Any Help?

My Code is:

```
void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
                DeleteRecursive(child);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

This is the message I am getting during delete operation:

```
01-01 01:28:43.440: W/System.err(4183): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:34)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.DeleteRecursive(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:35)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.stericsson.sdcard.Delete_sdcard1Activity.onCreate(Delete_sdcard1Activity.java:23)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 01:28:43.450: W/System.err(4183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the exception message also with the post.

Comment: Your coding style is not the java standard coding style. And also It is better to use curly brackets to include code blocks like this "if" block to improve the readability of your code.

Comment: The above code is fine. Can you put in the full stack trace that you get while deleting all the files ? @Manjla it is java standrard coding style.

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace!!!

Comment: @BigFatPig starting methods in capital letters is not the standard java coding style. starting methods with capital letters is the standard coding style for C# and such languages. Read http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf

Comment: Adding "fileOrDirectory.listFiles() != null" to the if condition solved my problem.Thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the listFIles() function may return null if the pathname denoted by the File object is NOT a directory or if some I/O error occurs.
As a standard practice, you should add a null check for the return value of listFiles().

Answer (score 0):

to delete files/folders recursively:

```
public boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

           return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: How can a void method return false?

Comment: oops, my bad, fixed it...   :)

Answer (score 0):

**Apache's commons-io FileUtils**

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("directory"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this: `if(fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())` should be `if(fileOrDirectory != null && fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())` and `filesOrDirectory.delete();` should be

```
   if(filesOrDirectory != null) {
       filesOrDirectory.delete();
   }
```